# How do you get a jar from your source folder after you compile your program?

Tags: java, file, compilation

I'm running Java in ProcessBuilder, and I'm having trouble launching the process because my file isn't there anymore.

`builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", getJar());`

By "isn't there," I mean that the getJar() method isn't returning the file that it was before I compiled the program.

These two functions worked until I compiled the program into a Jar itself.

```
public static void setJar(String file) 
{
    try {
        Jar = new File(Server.class.getResource("myFile.jar").toURI()).toString();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) { printToConsole(Format.ERROR, e.getMessage()); }
}

public static String getJar() { return Jar;}
```

**The project build:**

```
Project:
-> srcFolder
--> mypackage
---> Class
---> File
```

Comment: The file is not a file. It's a *resource*. When you use `getResource()`, when you are in an IDE, it may get an actual file from your development file tree. But when you compile into a jar, the resource is copied into the jar and is not a file any more. You can't make a `File` from it.

Comment: You want to run another java program for which you have the jar file inside your current program ?

Comment: @RealSkeptic so what should I be doing?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen If I understand you correctly, yes.

Comment: Why do you want to do that instead of just invoking the code directly in your current JVM?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not directly possible; java applications ship as an abstracted 'resource oracle' concept, and a resource can be anything; from a file, to an entry in a jar, to streamed from a database, an SFTP server, or even generated on the fly.

You then want to run `java -jar x`, where x must be an actual file.

Your only reliable option is to use the `getResource` call to obtain a resource, stream this into a temporary jar file, and then execute that. Making temp files and executing them is a bit tricky. Perhaps instead of shipping a java app inside an app and trying to make the OS run the app-in-an-app, maybe just invoke that app directly, and run it all in a single VM.